Proving projection bound using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
I'm reading a book The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class Book by J. Michael Steele. And on page 59 (first paragraph), I found the assertion that we can prove the projection formula
$$
P(v) = tx = \frac{\langle v, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle} x
$$
of $v$ onto $x$ by guessing $t$. Specifically, from the assumption that vector $x$ must be orthogonal to $v - tx$, i.e., $\langle x, v - tx \rangle = 0$, we infer that
$$
t = \frac{\langle v, x \rangle}{\langle x, x \rangle}. 
$$
Then, the author suggests to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that this choice of $t$ is optimal.
I tried different ways but I don't find how Cauchy–Schwarz inequality can be applied to prove optimality of $t$. Could you help me to find out the solution?
Thank you.

I was able to prove it.
Let's consider difference 
$$
\langle v-t'x, v-t'x \rangle - \langle v-tx, v-tx \rangle =\\
\langle t'x, t'x \rangle - 2t'\langle v,x \rangle + \langle t'x, t'x \rangle - (\langle v, v \rangle - 2\frac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\langle x,x \rangle} + \frac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\langle x,x \rangle}) =\\ \langle t'x, t'x \rangle - 2t'\langle v,x \rangle + \frac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\langle x,x \rangle}.
$$
We want to show that this expression is $\ge 0$.
I think here author suggested actually to apply not Cauchy-Schwarz but $2ab \le a^2 + b^2$. If we do so with $a = \|t'x\|$ and $b = \frac{|<v,x>|}{\|x\|}$, we get:
$$
\langle t'x, t'x \rangle - 2t'\langle v,x \rangle + \frac{\langle v,x \rangle^2}{\langle x,x \rangle} \ge \\ 2\|t'x\|\frac{|<v,x>|}{\|x\|} - 2t'\langle v,x \rangle =\\ 2|t'| \cdot 
|\langle v,x \rangle| - 2t'\langle v,x \rangle \ge 0.
$$

I suppose that the author understands optimality in the following sense: a real scalar $t^*$ is optimal if for any real scalar $t$ it holds that $$\Vert v - t^*x\Vert^2 \leq \Vert v - tx\Vert^2$$ for all $x$.
Indeed, let $t$ be an arbitrary real scalar. Then $$\Vert v - tx\Vert^2 = \Vert v\Vert^2 - 2t\langle v,x\rangle + t^2\Vert x\Vert^2 = \Vert x\Vert^2\underbrace{\left(\frac{\Vert v\Vert^2}{\Vert x\Vert^2}-\frac{2t\langle v,x\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert^2}+t^2-\frac{\langle v,x\rangle^2}{\Vert x\Vert^4}+\frac{\langle v, x\rangle^2}{\Vert x\Vert^4}\right)}_{=\left(t-\frac{\langle v,x\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert^2}\right)^2+\frac{\Vert v\Vert^2\Vert x\Vert^2-\langle v,x\rangle^2}{\Vert x\Vert^4}}.$$ For $t = t^* =\frac{\langle v,x\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert^2}$ we can make the whole term smaller as one non-negative term vanishes. However, for that argument to hold true, we have to make sure that indeed $$\Vert v\Vert^2\Vert x\Vert^2 - \langle v,x\rangle^2\geq 0.$$ But this follows from Cauchy-Schwarz: $$\Vert v\Vert^2\Vert x\Vert^2 - \langle v,x\rangle^2 \geq \Vert v\Vert^2\Vert x\Vert^2 - \Vert v\Vert^2\Vert x\Vert^2 = 0.$$

$| v |^2 | x |^2 - \langle v,x \rangle ^2 \ge 0$ follows form the fact that $|v-tx|^2 \ge 0$. So we don't need here CS bound. Actually, the author also presents these method as another proof but without using CS bound. On the opposite, we can prove CS using this approach.
